# Where to connect lm386 audio amp for raspberry pi?

Tags: pi-3, audio

I have an audio amp i built using the lm386 and [this schematic](https://www.flickr.com/photos/buildcircuit/8555864987/).

My question is : Where do i connect the input wire to the raspberry pi 3?

Edit : I am using the newest retropie operating system

Comment: Per joan's answer, there are several places you could solder or hook wires to to get yourself an analogue audio output on the Pi. Have you considered just adding a 3.5mm jack input to your amp? That leaves you looking for a simple cable between the amp and the Pi, and you can reuse the amp afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to guess you mean to amplify the audio coming out of the audio jack.

See the [Pi3B schematics](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/schematics/RPI-3B-V1_2-SCHEMATIC-REDUCED.pdf).

PP25 or PP26 seem a good choice if you can identify them on the board.

Personally I'd probably use one of GPIO 12/18 (right channel) 13/19 (left channel) which are all routed out to pins on the expansion header.  See https://pinout.xyz/

If you set them to audio mode (GPIO 12/13 mode ALT0, GPIO 18/19 mode ALT5) they will also have the audio PWM signal.

Comment: But how do I set the pins to audio mode?

Comment: Depends on the GPIO library you use.  With my pigpio you could for instance use `pigs m 12 0` to set GPIO 12 to mode ALT0.  See [pigs m](http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigs.html#M/MODES).